# Connection Pooling for Oracle in Microsoft enterprise Library

Tags: .net, oracle10g, c#-3.0, enterprise-library, odp.net

I am using Enterprise Library in my Winform application in .Net and Oracle is my database.
I want to implement connectino pooling in my application. 
My conenction strign is similar to one given below

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyName" connectionString="user id=MyID;password=MyPassowrd;data source=     (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MyHost)(PORT = 1234))(CONNECT_DATA =     (SID = MySID)))" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

To implement connection pooling, will this be a configuration change or a C# code change.

Please advice the best possible solution.

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

For connection pooling, the complete connection string should be same. ( ie. Either through code or through config the connection information should not be changed.) which means even the userid and password should not be changed.

When every thing is same, the connection pooling will automatically happen at the IIS. if not, the connection pooling will not work.